# Efficient thumbnail generation of huge pdf file?

Tags: pdf, memory, thumbnails

In a system I'm working on we're generating thumbnails as part of the workflow.
Sometimes the pdf files are quite large (print size 3m2) and can contain huge bitmap images.

Are there thumbnail generation capable programs that are *optimized for memory footprint* handling such large pdf files?

The resulting thumbnail can be png or jpg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is what I use for all my CLI graphics, so maybe it can work for you:

```
convert foo.pdf foo-%png
```

This produces three separate PNG files:

```
foo-0.png
foo-1.png
foo-2.png
```

To create only one thumbnail, treat the PDF as if it were an array (`[0]` is the first page, `[1]` is the second, etc.):

```
convert foo.pdf[0] foo-thumb.png
```

Since you're worrying about memory, with the `-cache` option, you can restrict memory usage:

> **-cache *threshold*** megabytes of memory available to the pixel cache.
>
> Image pixels are stored in memory
>   until *threshold* megabytes of memory have been
>   consumed.  Subsequent pixel operations
>   are cached on disk.  Operations to
>   memory are  significantly  faster but
>   if your computer does not have a
>   sufficient  amount of free memory you
>   may  want  to  adjust this threshold
>   value.

So to thumbnail a PDF file and resize it,, you could run this command which should have a max memory usage of around 20mb:

```
convert -cache 20 foo.pdf[0] -resize 10%x10% foo-thumb.png
```

Or you could use `-density` to specify the output density (900 scales it down quite a lot):

```
convert -cache 20 foo.pdf[0] -density 900 foo-thumb.png
```

Comment: Of course you can also specify a `-density` parameter if you have 3m² PDFs. Otherwise… default being 72 dots per inch you end up with… let me do some calculation… 24 megapixel image…

Comment: That would be nice. I'll add in `-resize` too.

Comment: @Blender: Yes. But `-density` is what applies when invoking the delegate (be it Ghostscript) which is an external command. Maybe the delegate cannot be memory-bounded?

Comment: I don't have any huge PDF's to try this on, but I would guess that Ghostscript has an option to restrict memory (and maybe `convert` pipes it over).

Comment: Does it resize properly? I haven't worked with such huge PDF files, so maybe it would benefit others with the same problem.

Comment: You may want to add `-flatten` to avoid transparent background. For several pages that combines them into one, though. I have tried `-background white` instead, but that didn't work for me. But `-flatten` will do great for one-page thumbnails.

Answer (score -1):

Should you care? Current affordable servers have 512 GB ram. That supports storing a full colour uncompressed bitmap of over 9000 inches (250 m) square at 1200 dpi. The performance hit you take from using disk is large.