# Creating Thumbnail from PDF without Adobe SDK

Tags: pdf, com

I've been looking for ways by which I can generate Thumbnails from pdf, as shown in the explorer. But the problem is that without Adobe Pro, the free version **does not expose all ihe COM interfaces**. Is there any other way? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) (which is what ImageMagick uses) will generate images in a wide variety of different image formats... if you need something really obscure then use the imagemagick wrapper, otherwise, I prefer the straight dope.

Comment: I read ur comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449903/advanced-pdf-parser-for-java/5462554#5462554 , and I got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford a commercial option, you could use [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) for this task, (or .Net version if that suits your needs better). Using this product you can create jpg/png/bmp images from the first page of your PDF files with the specified resolution, and then use them as thumbnails.

*Disclaimer: I am part of the development team of this product.*

Here are other SO questions proposing other approaches (not involving COM):

- [Using ImageMagic in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328401/efficient-thumbnail-generation-of-huge-pdf-file)
- [Thumbnail of a PDF page (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392640/thumbnail-of-a-pdf-page-java)

Comment: thank u. But is there no other *open-source* options, btw commercial apps are always welcome :)

Comment: The other 2 links that I mentioned have references to open source options, but I do not know any that can be used with COM.

Comment: the 2nd link was much useful. :)